Generalized Hamming weights for binary BCH codes
Given a linear binary code $C$, the $r$-th generalized Hamming weight $d_{r}(C)$ is the minimal support size of an $r$-dimensional subcode of $C$ (so $d_{1}(C)$ is simply the code's distance).
For a code length $n = 2^{m}-1$, and a designated distance $d=2t+1$, let's denote $\text{BCH}(n,d)$ the binary BCH code of distance $d$ (that corrects $t$ errors). It is known that the co-dimension of $\text{BCH}(n,d)$ is $tm$.
For concreteness, say we are interested in the constant $t$ case (say even $t=3$). What is known about the generalized Hamming weights $d_{r}(\text{BCH}(n,d))$ for all ranges of $r$? I found this paper, which seems to only give the answer when $r$ is either constant, or when $r$ is constantly-close to $k$, the code's dimension.
Specifically, what is known when, say, $r = 0.1m$? Any meaningful bound would be good, I'm not necessarily looking for the exact answer.
EDIT: I chose BCH just as a concrete example, but any linear, binary, code with "BCH-like" parameters is just as good (namely, constant distance with $O(\log n)$ co-dimension).
EDIT2: Cross-posted on math overflow.

I am not an expert in this, but I doubt much is known in the general case, this is a hard combinatorial problem.

Thanks! I figured that was the case, but was hoping maybe some bounds were known.

There is also this, which applies to irreducible cyclic codes, don't have time to see if relevant, but you may: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.2702.pdf

If I'm not mistaken, it looks like the results in that paper are "good" when the distance is large. I'm interested in the (binary) regime where the distance is constant and the co-dimension is logarithmic. We know that $O(1) = d_1 < d_2 < \ldots < d_k = n$, and $k$ is $n-O(log n)$, so basically the question is, is there a code for which the "jump" occurs at the beginning? Say, already $d_{\log n} > 2\log n$.

Maybe the bounty will help attract someone with more knowledge. Are you restricting yourself to BCH codes only?

No, good point. I added a clarification at the end of the post.

My non-expert feeling is that finding good bounds for $d_r$ would be easier on Reed-Muller codes.
